# FIle type association within Setup project

Tags: vb.net, deployment, installation, file-association

I have a VB.NET application. Next in this solution I have a Setup project which adds icon to target machine desktop, install some dll libraries and so on.

Next thing I want to do is associate one file type with this application (so if a user open particular file, the application is opened and shows content of this file). In setup project there is File types editor where I should be able to do that. On pictures below you can see how I set it (in my opinion it is OK but it doesn't work).

[image: New file type added with action]

[image: File type properties]

[image: Action prperties]

Xyz is file extension which I want to open with my application. When I install the application and open xyz file, this file is opened in notepad (I was opening xyz file with notepad before so nothing has changed). Can you tell me where is the problem? Thank you.